# Left arrow key not responding

Tags: mac, keyboard

**Machine:** iMac 27" late 2012
**Running:** MacOS Sierra 10.12.2

My iMac does not register a left arrow press in any program. However, the key works when I'm using modifier keys (Command + left arrow) or when I'm using a different account (leading me to believe that this is a software issue).

**Things I've tried so far:**

- Logging out
- Restarting
- Resetting NVRAM
- Removing com.apple.HIToolbx.plist (etc.) files
- Running defaults delete -g
- Viewing input on keyboard viewer (Command + left arrow registers, but left arrow alone does not)

Obviously I could set up another account but surely there's another way to fix this.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. Turns out an application called [aText](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/) was preventing me from being able to use that key. Quit the application and computer now works normally.